# Sqlite3 encerra INSERT sem erro

Tags: python-3.x

Em meu código eu executo um loop onde realizo o download de algumas imagens de uma URL e em seguida salvo o nome da imagem no `sqlite3`, porém depois de alguns `inserts` o código simplesmente passa a ignorar a linha onde esta o `insert`.

```
if hasattr(card, 'image_url'):
    print("Downloading card: " + card.name)
    card_image = 'images/' + card.set + '/' + card.name + '.jpg'

    if not card.image_url == None:
       try:
           urllib.request.urlretrieve(card.image_url, card_image)
       except (HTTPError, URLError) as error:
           print('Erro na URL, continuando...')
       except timeout:
           print('Time out atingido, continuando...')

    card_subtype = '|'.join(card.subtypes) if isinstance(card.subtypes, (list)) else card.subtypes
    card_color = '|'.join(card.colors) if isinstance(card.colors, (list)) else card.colors

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO cards VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [None, card.name, None, card.multiverse_id, str(card.type), card_subtype, card_color, card.rarity, card.mana_cost, card.power, card.toughness, card.set, card.text, card.flavor, card_image])

    print('Saving card: ' + card.name)
    connection.commit()
    print('Saved.')
```

A quantidade salva foi de 1231 registros, e em seguida apenas o primeiro print é executado, (downloading card...) e os outros 2 ao final do código são ignorados.

Comment: Vamos precisar ver mais código aí - você cooqcou a sequecia de if's e a chamada ao banco - mas o que faz o loop? de onde vem a variável "card"?  Como e criada a tabela? E sobretudo - o que acontecequando a escrita falha?  ele faz o primeiro print e passa para o próximo card? Ou o programa para e não faz mais nada?

Comment: Em particular isso não deveria mesmo acontecer - o meu chute aí é que voccê esteja chamando esse código dentro de um bloco "try...except" mais externo - algum erro acontece aí, e o except deixa passar em branco.